# Django, how to get total sum of methods with agregate sum

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

how to get total sum of methods in django using agregate ? I used this for fields and it work fine but for method it doesn t return anything.

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    client = models.ForeignKey('Client',on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def total(self):
        total = self.invoiceitem_set.aggregate(sum=Sum('subtotal'))
        return round(total[("sum")] or 0, 2)


class InvoiceItem(models.Model):
    invoice = models.ForeignKey('Invoice', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)
    
    def subtotal(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not reference a method, since the database does not know anything about `subtotal`. You thus should work with [**`F`** objects [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) to multiply the `price` with the quantity:

```
from django.db.models import F

class Invoice(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)
    client = models.ForeignKey('Client',on_delete=models.PROTECT)

    def total(self):
        return round(self.invoiceitem_set.aggregate(
            sum=Sum(F('price') * F('quantity'))
        )['sum'] or 0, 2)
```

With an `F` object, you refer to a field with that name.

Comment: ok. if it s more linked than that example, i mean price in table x and quantity in table y and then the sum will be on table z. i m worried if it can create some bugs or complications

Comment: @youssefmohamed: well you can not access any method. Because the methods defined at the Django/Python layer simply do *not* exist at the database level. The database does not know anything about models, Django, methods, etc. It only has tables, columns, etc. If you make a query, then this is translated to SQL, hence you can only use what the database knows.